# RecyclerView onItemClick Interface: get values in the Adapter or in the Activity?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a ViewHolder with an OnClickListener, which sends the click over an Interface to the underlying Activity. The only information i send is the AdapterPosition. In the Activity i then get the information out of the Activitie's reference to the ArrayList (which also fills the Adapter), using the position i get passed from the Adapter. I then use this to open a new Activity where i show this data.
Now, this works, but i just came to mind that this could cause problems, if i don't properly call notifyDataSetChanged/ItemInserted/Removed etc. and the Adapter shows a different List than the actualy up-to-date List in the Activity. I am right about this? Should i get the values out of the Objects IN the Adapter and pass them to the Activity or is my approach correct?

ViewHolder:

```
public class ExampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ImageView mImageView;
    public TextView mTextViewCreator;
    public TextView mTextViewLikes;

    public ExampleViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        mTextViewCreator = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_creator);
        mTextViewLikes = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_likes);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mListener != null) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                        mListener.onItemClick(position);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

MainActivity OnItemClick implementation:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(int position) {
    Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class);
    ExampleItem clickedItem = mExampleList.get(position);

    detailIntent.putExtra("imageUrl", clickedItem.getImageUrl());
    detailIntent.putExtra("creatorName", clickedItem.getCreator());
    detailIntent.putExtra("likeCount", clickedItem.getLikeCount());

    startActivity(detailIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple: Always make sure that you notify the adapter about changes. 
Otherwise its behavior becomes unpredictable.

Apart from that, your code seems to be fine

Comment: So you think my approach is correct and i should not get the values out of the items within the adapter?

Comment: It wouldn't make any difference since (as I understood your explanation) both point to the same list object.

Comment: But I would recommend doing it in the activity for the sake of code structure

Comment: You mean you would rather get the values in the Activity than the other alternative (in the Adapter)?

Answer (score 0):

My personal preference is that you send the model to the activity, that's what it's interested in, it doesn't care about your adapter position, and even if in the future your list became an expandable list or even a `ViewPager`, all the `Callback` (`Activity`) wants is the model to start the new screen.

You can change your listener method to

```
onItemClick(ExampleItem item)
```

and then you can set your listener when `onBindViewHolder` is called.